# How was the data loaded here with power query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

We have a task to be able to connect to HFM in Power BI. I found this article:

https://poweronbi.com/2016/04/from-hyperion-planning-or-hyperion-financial-management-to-power-bi/

but i dont understand HOW the database tables were/can be loaded from HFM into PowerBI. This is as far as the statement goes, without any demo or explanation in step1-2:

> I have attached a screenshot of the HFM data base, and you can load
>   all the tables listed in the left column and load it to Power BI with
>   Power Query.

There is no HFM connector in PowerBI. so how were they able to connect to begin with??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to connect directly to HFM. You can connect to the Oracle server where the HFM data is stored. That's the same information listed in the link you had shared as well. If you want details on how to connect to an Oracle server from power BI the following link should help you out:

https://www.edureka.co/community/41702/how-to-connect-to-oracle-database-from-power-bi

Comment: i see. is there a way to somehow utilize MDX instead to load data from HFM database into PowerBI? If so, could you give insights about it in your answer?

Comment: I haven't really explored this particular option...You may want to post that as a separate question to get a better response